# Using a substitution for a system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working some problems when preparing for my differential equations exam and I came across this one. It states:

Given the two systems:
$$ \begin{cases}x'(x,y) = y+x(x^2+y^2) \\ y'(x,y) = -x+y(x^2+y^2) \end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases}x'(x,y) = y-x(x^2+y^2) \\ y'(x,y) = -x-y(x^2+y^2) \end{cases} $$
Linearise these equation and find the nature of the critical point $(0,0)$. This was not an issue as I computed the Jacobians and found the eigenvalues. My issue arose in the second and third part of the question. It asks to do a transformation to $r$ with $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. Show that $r'<0$ and that $\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty}r(t) = 0$ for the second system of equations. What can we say about the point $0$.

When first looking at the transformation, polar coordinates stuck out to me, but I don't know if this is correct or how to apply it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the derivative of both sides in the identity $r(t)^2 = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$ you get $2 r(t) r'(t) = 2 x(t) x'(t) + 2 y(t) y'(t)$. So (for $r>0$) you have
$$
r' = \frac{xx'+yy'}{r} = \cdots
$$

Comment: I don't really see how to progress from that step. Could you explain how to do the substitution for one of the two systems?

Comment: Well, $x'$ and $y'$ are given, so you just insert them into the formula, and then the linear terms cancel and you're left with $\pm \frac{x^2(x^2+y^2)+y^2(x^2+y^2)}{r}=\pm\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{r}=\pm r^3$.

Comment: I see my mistake now. I forgot that $x^2+y^2 = r^2$, not $r$, thus my confusion of getting $r' = r$. Thank you for the help solving this problem, I understand it now.